# How can I delete an elemet of an array by idex in c#?

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

Let's think we have a list like this

```cs
int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

I want to delete an element of values by index.
I mean, the programme will ask an index, if the input is **3**, **values**' 4th index will be deleted.

I can't use **ArrayList**s 'cuz I'm writting a programme with 300 lines, and I don't want to convert all that Lists to ArrayList.

Comment: You cannot remove an element from an array. You can either create a new array without that element or rather use `List<int>` instead.

Comment: "Let's think we have a list like this" - that's not a list, it's an array. They're very different, and you can't resize an array after creation. You can create a *new* array, but that's not the same thing. Note that using `ArrayList` would also be a bad idea - non-generic collections are almost never as useful as the generic ones. You should use a `List<int>` - and 300 lines is a pretty small-scale refactor, to be honest.

Comment: tnx guys I guess it will be hard to convert all arrays but I'll try.d